# FFMPEG: using filters for adding transparent watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

how can i combine these two lines of code for adding transparent watermark (with Dynamic size)

```
ffmpeg -i 1.gif -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[logo];[0][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-5" -c:a copy output.gif

ffmpeg -i 1.gif -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.1[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-5" -c:a copy output.gif
```

i have tried the following code:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.gif -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.1[logo][video];[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[logo];[0][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-5" -c:a copy output.gif
```

i got the following Error:
Filter scale2ref has an unconnected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Outputs of every filter must be connected to something, and your `[video]` output pad of `scale2ref` is not, hence the error.</strike>

You need to feed `[video]` instead of `[0]` to the `overlay` filter:

You need to make sure all the filter input & output pads are connected. In your case, `format` and `overlay` need to use the output of `scale2ref` instead of reusing the input streams:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.gif -i logo.png \
  -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.1[logo1][video];\
                   [logo1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[logo];\
                   [video][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h-5" \
  -c:a copy output.gif
```

[Edit: fixed other labeling issues]

Comment: i got the same error - Filter scale2ref has an unconnected output

Comment: Yeah, try the edited version